# HTTP GET Request in MSSQL Database, nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, request

I have created a database which contains menu items (pizza for example)
How do I formulate the request if I want to get the pizzaName from the Pizza table and display it as a  in my html? I am new to this so it is a real challenge

I have tried it this way:

```
 function PizzaName(res){
    var options = {
       sql : 'SELECT pizzaName FROM Pizza WHERE pizzaID=1'
    }
    executeQuery(options, function(result){
    for(var column in result[0]){
        document.getElementById("pizzaName1").innerHTML = ("<h3>a" + column + "</h3>");
    }
    for(var row in result){
        for(var column in result[row]){
            document.getElementById("pizzaName1").innerHTML = ("<h3a>" + result[row][column] + "</h3>");       
        }        
    }
});
```

Comment: what is wrong with this ?

Comment: @underscore nothing happened.

Comment: `function PizzaName(res)` what is this function ?  where you calling it ? what is `res` parameter ?

Comment: this was coded by a group mate, I am trying to figure out how to make it work, I don't know what that parameter is either.

Answer (score 0):

In this,

```
document.getElementById("pizzaName1").innerHTML = ("<h3a>" + result[row][column] + "</h3>");
```

What is the `<h3a>` ? Should it be `<h3>` based upon your closing tag...?

Comment: spelling mistake, my bad. a should be outside the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this:

```
    for(var row in result){
    for(var column in result[row]){
        document.getElementById("pizzaName1").innerHTML = ("<h3a>" + result[row][column] + "</h3>");       
    }
```

why are you doing `result[row]`? at this point you already are dealing with one row, so assuming you have more than one column (which you wont, because your select statement is pulling out only pizzaname ). And since you are writing var column in row, you are already accessing the data in the row array- so column is not an index, it is the actual data. So perhaps the code would something like:

```
    for(var row in result){
    for(var column in row){
        document.getElementById("pizzaName1").innerHTML = ("<h3a>" + column + "</h3>");       
    }
```

Comment: Note that you can [edit] your answers, so you don't have to add multiple answers...